# Problem with permissions when trying to sync two external hard drives with rsync

Tags: permissions, osx, rsync

I'm trying to sync an external hardrive with the one containing my photo archive.

I wanted to begin with the basics, so I run:

```
rsync -aHm --delete /Volumes/archivo_1a/ /Volumes/archivo_1c/
```

In the first pass, it seemed to work allright. On subsequent runs, it gives me this message:

```
building file list ... rsync: opendir "/Volumes/archivo_1a/.DocumentRevisions-V100" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: opendir "/Volumes/archivo_1a/.TemporaryItems" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: opendir "/Volumes/archivo_1a/.Trashes" failed: Permission denied (13)
done
IO error encountered -- skipping file deletion
```

and fails to delete files that were deleted from the source disk.

The source disk is a partitioned disk; the other two partitions I use for time machine backups. Could that be the issue? Or what else might be happening.

Comment: What kind of filesystem is your target (/Volumes/archivio_1c)?  What user is rsync running as?  Does anything else write to the target filesystem besides rsync?  What are the permissions on the directories that it mentioned?

Comment: I'm not sure of the answers to all your questions. Here's my try:

MacOS Extended (jled) - GUID Partition

The user is me, the administrator of the iMac, the only user.

Nothing else writes into the target.

Actually, the output I copied above is from later trials. The first issues were with source disk permissions:

rsync: opendir "/Volumes/archivo_1a/.DocumentRevisions-V100" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: opendir "/Volumes/archivo_1a/.TemporaryItems" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: opendir "/Volumes/archivo_1a/.Trashes" failed: Permission denied (13)

Comment: The I/O issue you are having needs to be examined in the logs.

Comment: How i generate logs or where can I find them?

Comment: Use --ignore-errors.  Or consider Truck.app.  It's an rsync client for Mac that lets you just drag and drop to do simple operations like this.  http://bonhardcomputing.com/truck/  (disclaimer: I am a developer)

Answer (score 0):

You could use sudo but it would be better to use --exclude=".TemporaryItems" --exclude=".Trashes" so as to avoid fighting the OS for control of it's system folders.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just did that:

rsync -aH --exclude=“.DocumentRevisions-V100” --exclude=“.TemporaryItems” --exclude=“.Trashes” --delete /Volumes/archivo_1a/ /Volumes/archivo_1c/

The issue remains, though:
rsync: opendir "/Volumes/archivo_1a/.DocumentRevisions-V100" failed: Permission denied (13)
IO error encountered -- skipping file deletion
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-51/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]

Answer (score 0):

These files that failed to back up, are system and rsync files:

They can be safely ignored. --exclude

```
.DocumentRevisions-V100
.TemporaryItems
.Trashes
```

As referenced: [@Apple StackExchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/225905)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just did that:

rsync -aH --exclude=“.DocumentRevisions-V100” --exclude=“.TemporaryItems” --exclude=“.Trashes” --delete /Volumes/archivo_1a/ /Volumes/archivo_1c/

The issue remains, though:
rsync: opendir "/Volumes/archivo_1a/.DocumentRevisions-V100" failed: Permission denied (13)
IO error encountered -- skipping file deletion
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-51/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]

Comment: Ok, you are welcome. @AndrésVallejo